# Draft folder in Outlook shows messages but nothing in folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, my drafts folder shows 64 messages but when I click on the folder, there is nothing in it. I check 'Mark all as read' and it does nothing. It still shows 64 messages.

How do I clear this notification?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the /cleanviews command line switch?  [More info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/outlook/thread/0ae024d5-a00f-468f-b8d6-fa1996f80b2c)

[Be sure to read the linked to article from the above link too](http://www.outlook-tips.net/howto/commandlines.htm) - if you have created custom views, they'll be removed.

Comment: I will give it a shot, although I have not created any custom views. Thank you.

Comment: The custom views comment was only a warning that if you did have any they would get removed.  Did this work?